# How to define function from input

Tags: string, matlab, function

let's say we have function like below:

```
function Output=DoSomething(f)
...
...
end
```

where 'f' is a function that user inputs , like 'sin(t)' , 'x^2' or a vector of functions.
the function DoSomething gets f and perform some operation on it. for example, evaluates 'f' at t=pi/2,pi,2*pi,... and put result in Output vector. how can this be done in MATLAB? should f be an string variable? if yes, does it need to convert to another data type? i'm getting errors doing this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A couple of example ways to do this

1. Make the input f a function handle

   ```
   function [output] = dosomething(f, varargin) 
   output = f(varargin{:});  
   end

   >>f = @(x, y) sqrt(x.^2 + y.^2);
   >>dosomething(f, [3 5 8], [4 12 15])
   >>ans =
   >>5    13    17
   ```
2. Make f a string, and use 'eval'  (first is better practice, I think, this second one fails if nargin is less than 2, but not if nargin is >=3 even though the function doesn't use them.)

   ```
   function [output] = dosomething(f, varargin) 
   output = eval(f);  
   end

   >>f = 'sqrt(varargin{1}.^2 + varargin{2}.^2)';
   >>dosomething(f, [3 5 8], [4 12 15])
   >>ans =
   >>5    13    17
   ```
3. If you want to be able to input multiple functions, you can do something like

   ```
   function [output] = dosomething(f, varargin) 
   output = cellfun(@(x) x(varargin{:}), f, 'UniformOutput', false);  
   end
   >> f{1} = @(x, y) sqrt(x.^2 + y.^2);
   >> f{2} = @(x, y) atan2(x, y);
   >> A = dosomething(f, [3 5 8], [4 12 15]);
   >> A{1}
   ans =
   5    13    17
   >> A{2}
   ans =
   0.6435    0.3948    0.4900
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Wasn't sure whether to make this a comment or an answer...

It's really difficult to do this as there are all sorts of different ways of inputting functions into Matlab. I think that the easiest thing to do would be to make `f` an anonymous function, e.g.

```
f=@(x,y) x.^2+y.^2;
```

then inside the `DoSomething` function you can do `f(1,2)` or `f(1:10,11:20)`.

Note if the function is not defined using element-by-element operation (`.*`, etc.) then you can convert it so that it can take vector arguments by doing

```
syms q w
f=matlabFunction(f(q,w),'vars',[q w]);
```

which could prove useful.

Even if you don't make `f` an anonymous function for the input into `DoSomething`, converting whatever you get into either an anonymous function or a vector of values of `f` is probably a good idea in terms of performance.